# jQuery/js for loop, adding variable with different end number to separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following variables

```
example1 = 1
example2 = 32
example3 = 3345
etc all the way to something big, like
example100 = 222
```

I want to append each number into a separate div, each div labelled:

```
<div class = "exam1"> </div>
<div class = "exam2"> </div>
etc all the way to exam100
```

How can I do this using a for loop?

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 100; i++ ) {
     $(".exam"+i).empty();$(".age-"+i).append( **????** );

}
```

I just don't know how to add a number i onto the end of a variable so that it will work, any ideas?

Comment: why not use an array instead of 100 variables? one way would be: this["example" + i]

Comment: @Ghozt: If you have a textprocessor that can use Regular Expressions to replace text, you can easily replace your variables with an array. regex: `/example(\d+)/` replace with `example[$1]`. Then, add an array declaration at the top of your JS `var example = [];`

Answer (score 2):

You better use `array` instead of `variable`. Managing variables is quite difficut and unnecessary if almost all cases. Imagine if you want one hundred more then you will need to repeat the same excersie.

```
var arr = [1, 32, 3345 /* 100 elements */];

for ( var i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) 
{
     $(".exam"+i).empty();$(".age-"+i).append(arr[i-1]);    
}
```

But you can do with variables as well,

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 100; i++ ) 
{
     $(".exam"+i).empty();$(".age-"+i).append(window['example'+i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (also it isn't the best way to achieve what you need):

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 100; i++ ) {
     $(".exam"+i).empty();$(".age-"+i).append( window['example' + i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variables have been defined in the window scope (usually that means globally), you can access them like this:

```
var example1 = 100;
var i=1;
var t = window['example' + i];
console.log(t); // 100
```

Also you should seriously consider changing your 100 variables to one array (as the first comment to your question suggests).